# SVG Text rotation

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

I have a text with textContent "Design", that was transformed with css to be rotated 90 degree around the center (100,100), so it appears vertically.
It rotate the entire coordinate system around the center, I want the element (ie “Design”) alone should rotate

Original position:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Expected :

[image]

SVG:

```
<svg>
<text x="70" y="30" width="64" height="16" fill="black" transform="rotate(90,100,100)">Design</text>
</svg>
```

What is the problem ? why text element x position changed ? how could i rotate the text in fixed x-position ?

i want to rotate a text in fixed x-position ?

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 18):

If you would like text at `100,100` rotated `90` degrees then try the following:

```
<svg>
  <text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(100,100) rotate(90)">Design</text>
</svg>
```

This is much more straight-forward than the alternatives.

**Keep in mind** that the **order** of the `transform` parameters, `translate` and `rotate`, matters.

See the snippet below to see how it alters the outcome.

```css
.translate {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
  }
  
.rotate {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
  }
  
.reference {
  stroke: blue;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  }
```

```html
<svg class="reference" width="250" height="170" viewBox="-125 -25 250 170">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
  <line class="translate" x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="100"/>
  <circle class="rotate" cx="100" cy="100" r="3"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" class="reference">0,0</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(100,100) rotate(90)">TR</text>
</svg>

<svg class="reference" width="250" height="170" viewBox="-125 -25 250 170">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
  <path class="rotate" d="M -100 100 A 141.1 141.1 0 0 0 100 100"/>
  <line class="translate" x1="0" x2="-100" y1="0" y2="100"/>
  <text text-anchor="middle" class="reference">0,0</text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(90) translate(100,100)">RT</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 10):

**Follow these 3 steps:**

1. Wrap the `<text>` element in `<g>`.
2. Move/translate the `<g>` and therefore the `<text>`'s anchor point (here: effectively the top of the text, after rotation) to the desired position.
3. Rotate the `<text>`, set its anchor and **don't translate**, as in the examples below.

**Little explanation:**

The idea is to move the transformation reference point to where the `<text>` is and prevent both transformations from interfering with each other, otherwise, translation and rotation will be applied **at the same time** in reference to a point that is "somewhere else" — very difficult to control.

```html
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(42, 0)">
     <text
       text-anchor="start"
       transform="rotate(90)"
     >
       Design
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Alternatively, if you want the text baseline to be on the right (reads easier):

```html
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(42, 0)">
    <text
      text-anchor="end"
      transform="rotate(-90)"
    >
      Design
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is easier than the top answer

Answer (score 3):

The reason may be that the text-anchor is in the middle, so the (x, y) coordinates are for the center of the text and it is rotating about its center. You can add a `text-anchor="start"` attribute to the text, but then it won't be centered.

EDIT:
The reason the x-coordinate has changed is because you are rotating around the point(100, 100) and the text is at (70, 30). The text is therefore at (-30, -70) relative to the center of rotation so after rotation through 90 degrees will be at (70, -30). Why not rotate centred on (70, 30)?

Comment: It might be best to set the (x, y) coordinates of the text to (0, 0), then do the rotation, and then the translation: `transform="rotate(90,100,100) translate(70 30)"`